# Trigonometry unit circle help

Tags: trigonometry

Solve cos theta = 0.35 for theta \in [0,360). Round your final answer to the nearest tenth.

I thought the answer would be the inverse cos * (0.35) and that gives us 1.2 but that is the incorrect answer. ANy adivce on what im doing wrong or how to properly

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\cos^{-1}(\cos(\theta))=\cos^{-1}(0.35)$

You might have to change to radian measure first maybe?

Comment: I figured out what I was doing wrong. I was inputting pi instead of the 360 degrees thus causing my confusion. Thanks !!!

Comment: Ah, nice! Yeah if you wanted it in radians, 360 degrees would be $2\pi$

Answer (score 0):

It is Arc Cos (0.35) for the first solution and then
2pi - Arc Cos (0.35 for the second solution.